# isc-dhcp-server and compiz?

Tags: server, compiz, dhcp

I'm facing a very strange problem.

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. Everything is normal until I install `isc-dhcp-server`. When it's installed, my desktop becomes abnormal. All strings (file/folder names) are partially visible. When my mouse hovers, some strings re-appear but not all.

When I completely uninstall `isc-dhcp-server` (it removes `NetworkManager` and `network-manager-gnome` which are very useful), everything comes back to a normal state. If you need some screenshots I can add some.

After some research it seems coming from `compiz` because I have an error about `/usr/bin/compiz` (but not after all restarts)

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..

The problem came from the autologin. It was (visibly) too fast. I disabled it and wait for the first wifi connection and this problem disappears.

I hope this will help someone else.